# Await for custom login to sign in

Tags: reactjs, api, oauth, axios

I have an endpoint which I fetch and get the user details.

But when I do, if im not logged in, it redirects me to a custom login. Then when I sign in it takes me to the api which has the user details.

I need to somehow handle the response cookie from the login and then fetch the endpoint in react.

Any clue?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I dont have any yet. Im just trying to figure out if there's any way to do this.